# symfony2 relations doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Hello I am working with Symfony2 and I have these relationships:

table medico:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cita", mappedBy="medico")
*/
protected $citas;
```

table citas:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Medico", inversedBy="citas")
 */
 protected $medico;
```

Then I have this code which an appointment is created a physician.

```
  $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $cita = new Cita();
        $empleado = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $cita->setEmpleado($empleado);
        $cliente = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('miomioBundle:Usuario')->find($this->getRequest()->query->get('cliente'));
        $cita->setFechacita(new \DateTime($this->getRequest()->query->get('fecha')));
        $cita->setCliente($cliente);//asociacion de cita a usuario.
        $cita->setFechaoper(new \DateTime('now'));
        $medico = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('miomioBundle:Medico')->find($this->getRequest()->query->get('medico'));
        $cita->setMedico($medico);

        $em->persist($cita);
        $em->persist($cliente);
        $em->persist($empleado);
        $em->flush();
```

and then trying to get a doctor's appointments:

```
public function pintarAction($id)
    {
        $return_arr = array();
        $medico = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('miomioBundle:Medico')->find($id);
        $citas = $medico->getCitas();
        foreach($citas as $cita){
                return  new Response('entra');
                    $array['id'] = (string)$cita->getId();
                    $array['title'] = $cita->getCliente()->getNombre() . ' '. $cita->getCliente()->getApellido1();
                    $array['empleado'] = $cita->getEmpleado()->getUsername();
                    if ($cita->getInforme()){
                        $array['informe'] = $cita->getInforme()->getId();
                        $array['className'] = 'informe';
                    }
                    else{
                        $array['informe'] = 'NO';
                        $array['className'] = '';
                    }
                    $array['fecha'] = $cita->getFechaoper()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
                    $array['start'] = $cita->getFechacita()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                    $array['allDay'] = false;
                array_push($return_arr,$array);
         }

    return  new Response(json_encode($return_arr), 200, array('Content-Type', 'text/json'));
    }
```

where the variable $medico is ok. but the variable $citas is empty. why?

someone knows I'm doing wrong? greetings and thanks.

Comment: 1. your `pintarAction` method will exit as soon as you enter in the `foreach` loop, due to the `return` clause; 2. check if your db has real data for selected medico; 3. don't get mad, use [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle)!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you read the entities from the same unit of work you have just persisted the entities in. In the code you didn't fill the inverse side of One-To-Many association. Doctrine does it only when loads entity from the storage.

If that's the problem, you can fix it by changing the setter function:

```
function setMedico($medico) {
     $this->medico = $medico;
     $medico->getCitas->add($this);
}
```

Sure you must have method `Medico::getCitas()` defined

```
function getCitas() {
    return $this->citas;
}
```

And Medico constructor must initiate the `$citas` property:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->citas = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer but the problem not was result.

This is the owning side, inversedBy Because You specify the attribute:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Medico", inversedBy="citas")
*/
protected $medico;
```

This is the inverse side (Because It has the mappedBy attribute):

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Cita", mappedBy="medico")
 */
 protected $citas;
```

To make it more clean:

The owning side has to use the attribute of the OneToOne inversedBy, ManyToOne, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The inversedBy attribute contains the name of the association-field on the inverse-side.
While, for the inverse side:

The inverse side of a bidirectional relationship must refer to its owning side by use of the mappedBy attribute of the OneToOne, OneToMany, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The mappedBy attribute designates the field in the entity That is the owner of the relationship.

ManyToOne is always the owning side of a bidirectional assocation.

OneToMany is always the inverse side of a bidirectional assocation.

getters and setter this generator with doctrine: generate: entitites When I save a doctor's appointment I assign:

```
$ cita-> setMedico ($medico);
```

but when I do the loop in physician not work. this blank:

```
$ citas = $ medico-> getCitas ();
         foreach ($ citas as $ cita)
```

When I save the appointment the doctor would not have to update the collection of doctor?
thanks.